What is the best way to override functions of thirdparty plugins?
Sometimes I need to edit some plugins to my solutions.

If plugin has hooks and/or function_exist() checks - i can override it via function.php in my theme.
But another question - if author refactor the overrided function after update of plugin - it can broke my site, right?

Is it way to override plugins that not have this constructions to override via function.php?



"if author refactor the overrided function after update of plugin - it can broke my site, right?" - yes, but if they made a function pluggable like that then broke it then it's a bad move on their part. Possible yes, but really ought not happen, at least not without a few releases notice and deprecation warnings.

If a plugin doesn't provide hooks to modify its functionality the best way forward would be to fork your own version of it. You'd then be responsible for incorporating any upstream updates into your fork.

and pass on the request to the authors to add the hooks you need, or submit an MR yourself with them.
